# Gnuplot Point size for my own pattern type

Tags: gnuplot, point

I am trying to get different point sizes for my point types.

```html
TimeStamp Response
2   2
3   2
4   8
5   2
```

I am able to get different point sizes using this command 
plot 'num.dat' using 2 with points ps 2, '' u 3 with points ps 5

But if I want different point sizes for my own pattern types. Sizes remain the same.
The command I used is:
plot 'num.dat' using 2 with points pt "6" ps 2, '' u 3 with points pt "5" ps 5

[image: Same Point Size]

Can someone help in correcting my commands.

AH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably somewhere hidden in the manual...(couldn't find it right away). Since your point is a character you need to change it via `font ",size"`.

**Code:**

```
set samples 10
plot '+' u 1:($1**2) w p pt "1" font ",8" ti "fontsize 8", \
     ''  u 1:($1**2+10) w p pt "2" font ",12" ti "fontsize 12", \
     ''  u 1:($1**2+20) w p pt "2" font ",16" ti "fontsize 16", \
     ''  u 1:($1**2+30) w p pt "4" font ",20" ti "fontsize 20"
```

**Result:**

[image]